# Custom post type not displaying all entries

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

[This is using a custom post type](http://safetyspeakers.ca/safety-speakers) that I've set up in the functions.php file. 
What I was hoping to get some advice one was why I have 14  entries in my custom "SPEAKERS" post type but only have 10 showing on my page? What might be limiting it?

This is what I put in my functions.php page

```
// Creates Speakers post type
register_post_type('speakers', array(
'label' => 'Speakers',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'speakers'),
'query_var' => true,
'supports' => array(
'title',
'editor',
'excerpt',
'trackbacks',
'custom-fields',
'comments',
'revisions',
'thumbnail',
'author',
'page-attributes',)
) );
```

This is a screenshot of all 14 of my speakers, but when you go to my speakers page you only see 10.

[image]

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only see ten posts because that is the amount of posts per page set by default in the back end under 'Settings -> Reading -> Blog pages show at most'

[image: Screenshot reading]

You can either set that to 14 to display all your 14 posts, or you can use [`pre get posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) or [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to alter the main query/create a custom query to change the number of posts shown on a page.